# Jquery calendar of events

Tags: jquery, html

I need a little help and facilitate the work. I need to create a simple calendar with highlighted events. Is there a jQuery plugin, which would be the simplest way?

[image: Calendar]

Comment: have you tried to [search](https://www.google.ca/search?q=jquery+calendar+highlighted+events) for this yet?

Comment: Please be more specific about your requirement for "highlighted events."

Comment: OMG - It **HAS** to be easier to type `jquery calendar` in google than it is to post this question. I can't believe the increasing number of these ridiculous questions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a big fan of [Kalendae](https://github.com/ChiperSoft/Kalendae), it don't even need jQuery to work.

Here is a demo: http://chipersoft.github.com/Kalendae/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Comment: I believe that's for just picking dates. Not for events etc..

Comment: You can make that calendar do pretty much anything you want.

Comment: Depends. How dirty is your apartment? :P

Answer (score 0):

These don't seem to be exactly what you need, but if you can't find a perfect fit, they might be helpful in creating what you need...

The jQuery UI Datepicker:  http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Adam Shaw's FullCalendar: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/